# Infinite homogeneous system and linear independence

Tags: linear-algebra

For $J \geq K$, consider a $J \times K$ matrix $M$ created by stacking row vectors $M(j)$ for $j=1,...,J$. We know the following are equivalent:

(a) The homogeneous system $M z=0$, where $z$ is a $K$-vector, has only trivial solution $z=0$.

(b) $M$ contains $K$ linearly independent rows.

Now generalize to the case in which $j$ takes on a continuum of values, say all values in $[0,1]$.  Suppose that there is no nonzero  $K$-vector $z$ such that $M(j)z=0$ for all $j$.  Does this imply existence of $K$ linearly independent row vectors $M(j)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose you have a function $M: I \to  V$, where $I$ is an arbitrary index set and $V$ a vector space of finite dimension $K$, such that there is no nonzero
$z \in  V^*$ that annihilates $M(j)$ for all $j \in I$.

Consider a set $S = (s_1, \ldots, s_{r}) \subseteq I$ of maximum cardinality $r$ such that $M(s_1), \ldots, M(s_r)$ are linearly independent.  If $r < K$, there is a nonzero vector $z \in V^*$ that annihilates all $M(s_i)$.  But for every
$s \in I$, $M(s_1), \ldots, M(s_r)$ and $M(s)$ are linearly
dependent, so $M(s)$ is in the linear span of $M(s_1), \ldots, M(s_r)$, and then $z$ annihilates $M(s)$ as well.  By assumption, this can't happen.  Therefore $r=K$, i.e. there are $K$ linearly independent vectors $M(s_1), \ldots, M(s_K)$.

Comment: I'm confused by the sentence beginning "But for every $j∈I$, $M(s_1),…,M(s_r)$ and $M(s)$ are linearly dependent,..."  What is $M(s)$?

Comment: Sorry, typo.  I'll fix it.